# Why will my react input validation work in a browser but not a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a puzzle game where I am trying to validate a user submitted word against the main answer or a *potential* array of alternative answers/spellings. I then change the input styles, count points, etc. if it is valid.

For some reason, my validation works perfectly in a browser, but when I try it on a phone, the altSpellings array answers are the only accepted one. It never accepts the main answer (first if statement) if the altSpellings array exists. If the altSpellings array is empty, then the first if statement will pass if valid.

Any idea why this is happening, or what I could be doing wrong?

Here is the event handler:

```
    const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const submission = el.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    if ((submission === word.word.toLowerCase().trim()) ) {
        setText(word.word);
        setDisabled(true);
        setSubmitStyle("correct");
        setHelpStyle("help correct");
        setSubmitText(wordPoints);
        scorePass(wordPoints);
        completionPass(wordPoints);
        this.el.blur();
    } 
    else if (word.altSpellings && word.altSpellings.some(element => { return submission === element.toLowerCase().trim() })) {
        setText(word.word);
        setDisabled(true);
        setSubmitStyle("correct");
        setHelpStyle("help correct");
        setSubmitText(wordPoints);
        scorePass(wordPoints);
        completionPass(wordPoints);
        this.el.blur();
    }
    else if (text === ""){
        setSubmitStyle("");
    }
    else {
        setText("");
        setSubmitStyle("incorrect");
        setHelpStyle("help incorrect");
    };
};
```

And the values when I log them elsewhere:

```
submission = "don't"
word.word.toLowerCase().trim() = "don't"
word.altSpellings.toString() = "do not,dont"
```

When I change the submission to "dont" or "do not" it passes on mobile, while any of the three will pass on desktop (as intended). Super strange.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what values of `submission` and `word` look like. So the generic advise is to log values of those using alert (on mobile browser). and eventually find out why the logic doesnot pass the first condition.

```
const submission = el.value.toLowerCase().trim();
alert(submission);
alert(word.word.toLowerCase().trim());

/*conditions...*/
```

Comment: thanks for this. just ran the test with alerts and the same errors happen as before. however, the variables print the exact same in the alerts and only fail larger validation after i close the second alert.

Comment: i also tried it on a word that has no word.altSpellings and the variables printed the same and passed the validation as expected, super strange.

Comment: I doubt that there's spaces in those values so try putting delimiters around such as `alert("_" + submission + "_")`. Anyway, you should provide the exact values of `submission` and  `word` in your question.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i added the values to my question. i also tried with the delimiters on mobile and again the value passed the test visually but did not pass the actual conditional. the same value still works as intended on desktop.

Comment: @Taylor I found no problem with your provided values on my phone and desktop. So my last advice for you is trying simplifying the logic and testing with other values. and consider the type of your phone's browser as well as keyboard.